# Keras: How to check what is the data type expected in the input layer?

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I want to check what is the default data type expected in the input layer, and how to change it?

Answer (score 2):

If you have keras model just do:

```py
print(model.inputs[0].dtype
```

You can pass desired datatype while creating a model. For example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf 
print(tf.__version__) # 2.0.1

x = tf.keras.layers.Input((2,), dtype=tf.float64)
res = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, dtype=tf.float64)(x)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(x, res)

print(model.inputs[0].dtype, model.outputs[0].dtype) # <dtype: 'float64'> <dtype: 'float64'>
```

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to give more details about the three main lines in the middle of your code? I mean how can I apply this to Conv2D or LSTM as first layer? Thank you.